# Select count from particular foreign key in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to create an `SQL` statement that will tell me how many books where written by a given author.

When you know the authorid (foreign key to `books` table) it's easy:

```
select count(*) from books where authorid = 25;
15
```

You can see that author with id 15 has written 15 books. Is it possible to create a statement for all the authors such that the ouput is as follows?

```
author_id, author_name, number_of_books
1          Michael      15
2          Robin        7
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a `group by` clause:

```
select 
    a.author_id,
    a.author_name,
    count(*) as number_of_books
from
    authors a inner join
    books b on b.author_id = a.author_id
group by
    a.author_id,
    a.author_name
order by 
    number_of_books
```

Comment: I asked why `inner join` in another answer and this was told me so I will paste it here. `In most SQL databases today, JOIN is a synonym for INNER JOIN. I prefer the verbose but unambiguous full name.`

Comment: May I ask one smaller question? Is it possible to `order by` number_of_books? I tried it with `group by` with this error `Error: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause` and with `order by` with this error `Error: near "group": syntax error` ... but it would be great if it was possible.

Comment: @MichaelFriedrickson Great, it seems that `order by` must follow `group by`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a GROUP BY query:

```
select author_id, author_name, count(*) as number_of_books 
   from books
   join author on books.author_id = author.id 
   group by author_id, author_name;
```

Comment: Seems to work. Why is there `as number_of_books` I used the statement without it.

Comment: 'as number_of_books' gives that name to the output column.

Comment: I thought it, but the heading wasn't shown. Maybe it's in another DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    books.author_id, authors.author_name, COUNT(books.author_id) AS number_of_books
FROM
    authors INNER JOIN books ON books.author_id = authors.id
GROUP BY
    author_name;
```

Also, make sure that the books.author_id column is NOT NULL otherwise performance will suffer.

Comment: This seems to be more precise than the other answers but why did you used `inner join` instead of only `join` and `sum` instead of `count`. Has it a meaning here? @Stuart haven't used it and it works too.

Comment: In most SQL databases today, `JOIN` is a synonym for `INNER JOIN`. I prefer the verbose but unambiguous full name. As for SUM, you want a sum of books, even if count(*) in this case produces identical results. Again, this is in the name of clarity. You will appreciate this clarity when you are maintaining the code years from now, or somebody else is!

Comment: Isn't SUM(books.author_id) going to *add up* all the author IDs?

Comment: Also, books.author_id should be in the GROUP BY list.

Comment: Stuart is right. I don't know what I was thinking. I will wait a few minutes for the OP to read his comment and then I will delete my post. I am honoured to have gotten the selected answer, but I certainly don't deserve it here!

Comment: @dotancohen That's OK, I will accept the solution that is very similar to yours. I haven't noticed it too.

Comment: I fixed this solution with the best-performing solution. Count on the specific column, and be sure that it is NOT NULL for performance.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the other solution (to be fair) because it was fastest correct

Comment: @xralf: You did the right thing. I am interested in seeing the correct answer get the credit, not myself!